# sendReliable message sometimes not received by opposite peer

Tags: google-play-games

I've created a real time game for Google Play Game Services. It's in the later alpha stages right now. I have a question about sendReliableMessage. I've noticed certain cases where the other peer doesn't receive the message. I am aware that there is a callback onRealTimeMessageSent and I have some code in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageSent(int i, int i2, String s) {
    if(i== GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        lastMessageStatus=i;
        sendToast("lastMessageStatus:"+Integer.toString(lastMessageStatus));
    }
}
```

My games render loop is checking every iteration the value of lastMessageStatus and if there was something other than STATUS_OK I'm painting a T-Rex right now.

My question is is checking the sent status really enough? I also could create source code where the sender has to wait for an Acknowledged message. Each message would be stamped with a UUID and if ack is not received within a timeout then the sender would send the message again? Is an ACK based system necessary to create a persistent connection?

I've noticed certain cases where there is some lag before the opposite peer received the reliable message and I was wondering is there a timeout on the sendReliable message? Google Play Services documentation doesn't seem to indicate in the documentation that there is a timeout at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reliable messages are just that, **reliable**.  There are not a lot of use cases for the `onRealTimeMessageSent` callback for reliable messages because, as you said, it does not guarantee that the recipient has processed the message yet.  Only that it was sent.

It may seem annoying, but an ACK-based system is the best way to know for sure that your user has received the message.  A UUID is one good way to do this.  I have done this myself and found it to work great (although now you have round-trip latency).

As far as timeout, that is not implemented in the RealTime Messaging API.  I have personally found round trip latency (send message, receive ACK in callback) to be about 200ms, and I have never found a way to make a message fail to deliver eventually even when purposefully using bad network conditions.